# Consulta fechas SQL

Tags: sql, date

Tengo una tabla con una columna de formato (Tipo `DATE`) `"2023-07-28 12:00:00.000"` (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff). Necesito hacer una consulta por fecha especifica, traerme todos los registros que posean en la columna "`Fecha`" un dia puntual, ... pero no logro conseguirlo. He intentado todo, pero en cada consulta me arroja distintos errores o no me trae nada ¿Alguna recomendación?

Comment: Hola. Muestra la consulta que estás intentando, así como el mensaje de error, pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Indica el DBMS que estas ocupando y la estructura de tus tablas como ejemplo, edita tu pregunta. Pon un ejemplo mínimo verificable que hayas intentado para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte, aquí las preguntas que no muestran algún intento no son bien recibidas y terminan por ser cerradas, edita tu pregunta y agrega lo que sea necesario para entender tu problema, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Comment: Deberías verificar el formato de fecha de tu base de datos y el de el lenguaje de programación que estas usando. Ocasionalmente la discrepancia de formatos genera fallos al consultar.